# TensorflowJS (TFJS) image classification shape mismatch after conversion from python in Angular Ionic Project

Tags: javascript, python, angular, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

My model shape is:

[image]

---

I have earlier trained the model in python, saved it with `model.save('model.h5')` and converted it to JS with `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras model.h5 mobilenetv2`

After this, I have tried to use TensorflowJS using Angular to predict images.

The shape that worked in python:

```
print(test_data[0][0].shape)
>>> (32, 224, 224, 3)
```

My imports in Typescript file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Camera, CameraOptions} from '@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera/ngx';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {LayersModel} from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
```

My variable declaration:

```
model: LayersModel;
```

My first code:

```
async detectBtn(images: any) {
    this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('/assets/mobilenetv2/model.json');
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(images[0]);

    img.onload = (event) => {
      const imgWidth = img.naturalWidth;
      const imgHeight = img.naturalHeight;
      this.detect(img);
    };
  }

  async detect(image: any) {
    const tfimage = tf.browser.fromPixels(image).resizeBilinear([244,244]);
    console.log(this.model.predict(tfimage));
  }
```

And the corresponding error log:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error when checking : expected input_2 to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [244,244,3]
Error: Error when checking : expected input_2 to have 4 dimension(s), but got array with shape [244,244,3]
```

My second tweak:

```
async detect(image: any) {
    const tfimage = tf.browser.fromPixels(image).resizeBilinear([244,244]);
    console.log(this.model.predict(tfimage.reshape([null,244,244,3])));
  }
```

And the corresponding error log:

```
Error: Size(178608) must match the product of shape ,244,244,3
```

My third tweak:

```
async detect(image: any) {
    const tfimage = tf.browser.fromPixels(image).resizeBilinear([244,244]);
    console.log(this.model.predict(tfimage.reshape([1,244,244,3])));
  }
```

And the corresponding error log is:

```
Error when checking : expected input_2 to have shape [null,224,224,3] but got array with shape [1,244,244,3].
```

I have tried most possible combinations but it is not working. Please help me with some solution.

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.36",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^5.37.3",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "3.3.4",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.2.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.0.0",
    "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.1.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.15.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.15.0",
    "@types/offscreencanvas": "^2019.6.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.1",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~13.1.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.3.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tfimage.expandDims(0)` solved the issue. Also, to better get the results with Typescript, there are few tweaks to be made in order to cast the prediction results as Tensor and later convert it as array.

Therefore the code is:

```
async detect(image: any) {
    const imageResize = tf.image.resizeBilinear(
      tf.browser.fromPixels(image),
      [224, 224],
      false
    );
    const tensor = (this.model.predict(imageResize.expandDims(0)) as tf.Tensor).dataSync();
    console.log(tensor);
  }
```